# How to modify "shop by" to display category

Tags: layered-navigation

I'm trying to get the shop by filters to display a new section called category.  I managed to edit template/category/layer/view.phtml to get it to display the category section but the subcategories display all the options including subcategories, subsubcategories, and so on.  I only want to display the categories that are one level higher than the main category.  Sort of what it looks like in a dropdown navigation menu.  I've also tried several coding strategies inside template/category/layer/filter.phtml.  I've gotten close but managed to mess up the main navigation in the process.

The category filter needs to work for all product selections from the main menu, so I don't want to modify all 1800 products to add a field that contains the parent category.  I've gotten so close to getting it to work but I have problems using getLevel, and getID on certain variables.

Comment: Have any of the proposed solutions worked for you?

Comment: Figured it out! It involves modifying template catalog layer view.phtml

Comment: I figured out the problem on my own, so none of the proposed solutions in this forum worked for me.  But thanks for the help everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Categories in layered navigation do not work like attributes and are not 'filterable' - and as such we usually recommend setting up a dropdown or multiselect attribute type to apply to products so that you can provide filtering of this level.

It's not "sexy" and it's not a code-based solution, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some layered navigation extension that does the job for you, you can rewrite the categories filter **model** `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category`, not the template to show parent category and subcategories.

And then modify the method like

```
protected function _getItemsData()
{
    if ('catalogsearch' == Mage::app()->getRequest()->getModuleName()) {
        $items = parent::_getItemsData();

    }


    $currentCategory = $this->getCategory();

    $root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
            ->load($this->getLayer()->getCurrentStore()->getRootCategoryId()) ;

    $categories = $isStatic2LevelTree ? $root->getChildrenCategories() : $currentCategory->getChildrenCategories();


    if ($isStatic2LevelTree)
        $this->getLayer()->setCurrentCategory($root);

    $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()
        ->addCountToCategories($categories);


    $data = array(); 
    ....
    ....
    //TODO add your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian,
First of all....`Magento Layernation only show it subcategory`.It did not `provide show current category parent category`...

Show if you...

```
current category  parent category then follow below.But it not provide product count on basic of current category product Collection
$parentId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentCategory()->getId();
```